# Open a "chrome-extension://" URI from command line

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, osx-lion, google-chrome-extensions

`chrome-extensions://` is a non-standard URI used by the Chrome browser.

How do I open a page like

> chrome-extension://mijlebbfndhelmdpmllgcfadlkankhok/app.html

in the Chrome browser from command line? I'm on OS X Lion.

Comment: Could you give us an actual example of a page that should open in chrome?

Comment: On which system?

Comment: @m4573r edited.

Comment: @terdon It depends on the extension you installed. I installed `Quick Note` which is the one I pasted.

Comment: Question answered here:
https://superuser.com/a/979678

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I open a non-http URL (Chrome extension) in Google Chrome from the terminal in OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/836769/how-can-i-open-a-non-http-url-chrome-extension-in-google-chrome-from-the-termi)

Answer (score 1):

```
'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' "chrome-extension://chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall/onetab.html"
```

Don't try to combine this with `open -a`. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, Just type the following command in the terminal

```
google-chrome "chrome-extension://mijlebbfndhelmdpmllgcfadlkankhok/app.html"
```

You can even send some flags to open in a new window without search bar.

Comment: `google-chrome` is not part of the OS X distribution of Chrome.

Comment: @misterbee, sure it adds *a* binary to $PATH though, right? Happen to know what it is?