# How can I open a non-http URL (Chrome extension) in Google Chrome from the terminal in OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, bash, google-chrome-extensions

I'm trying to add a shortcut to open Chrome with a non-http url from a bash script.  This is what I've got:

```
/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" 'chrome-extension://hgmloofddfasdfasdffgcellkdadsfadsfbjeloo/RestClient.html#RequestPlace:saved/2'
```

Since the argument doesn't start with "http" Chrome tries to open it as a file, which of course doesn't exist, nor is it what I want.

Is there a way to make Chrome treat that as a url?

Edit:

@mjb - that's almost working.  Thank you.

The extension (Advanced Rest Client) is installed locally.  However, there's something different about loading it as a file and loading it with "chrome-extension://".  When I load it as a file, I don't get the data (my rest requests) that has been saved as part of the app.  Without that, it's useless.

Here's what I'm running from bash:

```
/usr/bin/open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app /Users/me/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/hgmloofdphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/3.1.7_0/RestClient.html
```

It loads my app, and it comes up - just without my context/data.  When I click the extension in Chrome, it uses the following url:

```
chrome-extension://hgmloofdphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/RestClient.html#RequestPlace:saved/2
```

Note that the hash on the end makes no difference.  The UUID is the same as the local directory.

I also tried loading it with:

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffgcellkdfbfbjeloo/RestClient.html
```

That just brings up the Chrome Web Store page for this app.

The data I want to use does appear to be in the database file for this extension, which is in:

```
/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases/chrome-extension_extension_hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo_0/5
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `open` attempts to process the passed URL before passing it on to Chrome.  Since it doesn't recognize the 'chrome-extension' scheme, it interprets it as a relative file path.

Instead, you can use AppleScript to accomplish this.

```
osascript <<EOD
set theURL to "chrome-extension://nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda/html/craw_window.html"
tell application "Google Chrome"
 if windows = {} then
  make new window
  set URL of (active tab of window 1) to theURL
 else
  make new tab at the end of window 1 with properties {URL:theURL}
 end if
 activate
end tell
EOD
```

Note that the above code is actually AppleScript wrapped in a bash heredoc and passed to the `osascript` command, so you can drop it right into the terminal or a shell script.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you mean to or not, you're telling Chrome to open a local file.

If you're trying to navigate to an extension online, it has an https address, like Evernote Web Clipper:

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evernote-web-clipper/pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc?hl=en-US
```

If your goal is to load a local extension, you have to give the full path to the extension, not the relative path. By default, you can find them here:

```
/Users/<USER>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions
```

But these do not have a local `chrome-extension://` URL. If I understand correctly, you would want to do:

```
$ /usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" "/Users/<USER>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/<EXTENSION-ID>"
```

Where `<USER>` is your user and `<EXTENSION-ID>` is the unique identifier of your extension. That will bring Chrome into a directory navigation mode where you can then load whatever file you're after from there.

If this doesn't help, it'd be good to clarify what your goal in the original question.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but this post is insightful so thank you. `open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall/`

Answer (score 0):

You can make an AppleScript app to open specific URL scheme with Google Chrome.

1. **Create a new applescript**

> ```
> on open location theURL
>   tell application "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"
>       set newwindow to make new window
>       activate
>       set URL of active tab of newwindow to theURL
>   end tell
> end open location
> ```

2. Save this AppleScript script as an **application**
3. Edit **Info.plist** and add a new key `URL types` (array)

[image: URL Scheme Info.plist]

> ```
> <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
>     <array>
>         <dict>
>             <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
>             <string>Applescript urls</string>
>             <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
>             <array>
>                 <string>chrome-extension</string>
>             </array>
>             <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForScheme</key>
>             <true/>
>         </dict>
>     </array>
> ```

4. Launch the app one time to register it and the next time you open a chrome-extension link it will open it on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it doesn't use `open`:

```
'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' "chrome-extension://chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall/onetab.html"
```

I use this in a cron job.